# Why does SQL 2005 SSIS component install fail?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

I am trying to install SSIS on our production SQL 2005 SP2 box.  Each time I try, the install/setup screen results in failure, starting with the native client, and moving on down.  Screen shots below show what I see:

[image: begin install]

[image: install result]

Here is the result of clicking on the status link to the right of the native client after the install failed:

```
=== Verbose logging started: 3/28/2012  16:38:08  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 3.01.4000.4042  Calling process: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\setup.exe ===
MSI (c) (DC:00) [16:38:08:875]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (DC:00) [16:38:08:875]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (DC:00) [16:38:08:875]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: {F9B3DD02-B0B3-42E9-8650-030DFF0D133D}
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (DC:00) [16:38:08:875]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (DC:00) [16:38:08:875]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (DC:00) [16:38:08:875]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (DC:00) [16:38:08:875]: Attempting to enable all disabled priveleges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (DC:00) [16:38:08:875]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (90:F0) [16:38:08:875]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:08:875]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:08:875]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:08:875]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: {F9B3DD02-B0B3-42E9-8650-030DFF0D133D}
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:08:875]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:08:890]: Warning: Local cached package 'C:\WINDOWS\Installer\65eb99.msi' is missing.
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:08:890]: User policy value 'SearchOrder' is 'nmu'
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:08:890]: User policy value 'DisableMedia' is 0
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:08:890]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownMedia' is 0
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:08:890]: SOURCEMGMT: Media enabled only if package is safe.
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:08:890]: SOURCEMGMT: Looking for sourcelist for product {F9B3DD02-B0B3-42E9-8650-030DFF0D133D}
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:08:890]: SOURCEMGMT: Adding {F9B3DD02-B0B3-42E9-8650-030DFF0D133D}; to potential sourcelist list (pcode;disk;relpath).
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:08:890]: SOURCEMGMT: Now checking product {F9B3DD02-B0B3-42E9-8650-030DFF0D133D}
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:08:890]: SOURCEMGMT: Media is enabled for product.
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:08:890]: SOURCEMGMT: Attempting to use LastUsedSource from source list.
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:08:890]: SOURCEMGMT: Trying source C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\Cache\.
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:08:890]: SOURCEMGMT: Source is invalid due to invalid package code (product code doesn't match).
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:08:890]: Note: 1: 1706 2: -2147483646 3: sqlncli.msi 
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:08:890]: SOURCEMGMT: Processing net source list.
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:08:890]: Note: 1: 1706 2: -2147483647 3: sqlncli.msi 
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:08:890]: SOURCEMGMT: Processing media source list.
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:09:921]: SOURCEMGMT: Trying media source F:\.
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:09:921]: Note: 1: 2203 2: F:\sqlncli.msi 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:09:921]: SOURCEMGMT: Source is invalid due to missing/inaccessible package.
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:09:921]: Note: 1: 1706 2: -2147483647 3: sqlncli.msi 
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:09:921]: SOURCEMGMT: Processing URL source list.
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:09:921]: Note: 1: 1402 2: UNKNOWN\URL 3: 2 
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:09:921]: Note: 1: 1706 2: -2147483647 3: sqlncli.msi 
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:09:921]: Note: 1: 1706 2:  3: sqlncli.msi 
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:09:921]: SOURCEMGMT: Failed to resolve source
MSI (s) (90:D4) [16:38:09:921]: MainEngineThread is returning 1612
MSI (c) (DC:00) [16:38:09:921]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (DC:00) [16:38:09:921]: MainEngineThread is returning 1612
=== Verbose logging stopped: 3/28/2012  16:38:09 ===
```

Here is the log visible when I click the failed status for MSXML6:

```
=== Verbose logging started: 3/28/2012  16:38:12  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 3.01.4000.4042  Calling process: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Setup Bootstrap\setup.exe ===
MSI (c) (DC:58) [16:38:12:250]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (DC:58) [16:38:12:250]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (DC:58) [16:38:12:250]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: {56EA8BC0-3751-4B93-BC9D-6651CC36E5AA}
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (DC:58) [16:38:12:250]: Client-side and UI is none or basic: Running entire install on the server.
MSI (c) (DC:58) [16:38:12:250]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (c) (DC:58) [16:38:12:250]: Cloaking enabled.
MSI (c) (DC:58) [16:38:12:250]: Attempting to enable all disabled priveleges before calling Install on Server
MSI (c) (DC:58) [16:38:12:250]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (90:58) [16:38:12:265]: Grabbed execution mutex.
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:265]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:265]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:265]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: {56EA8BC0-3751-4B93-BC9D-6651CC36E5AA}
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:265]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:265]: Warning: Local cached package 'C:\WINDOWS\Installer\ce6d56e.msi' is missing.
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:265]: User policy value 'SearchOrder' is 'nmu'
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:265]: User policy value 'DisableMedia' is 0
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:265]: Machine policy value 'AllowLockdownMedia' is 0
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:265]: SOURCEMGMT: Media enabled only if package is safe.
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:265]: SOURCEMGMT: Looking for sourcelist for product {56EA8BC0-3751-4B93-BC9D-6651CC36E5AA}
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:265]: SOURCEMGMT: Adding {56EA8BC0-3751-4B93-BC9D-6651CC36E5AA}; to potential sourcelist list (pcode;disk;relpath).
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:265]: SOURCEMGMT: Now checking product {56EA8BC0-3751-4B93-BC9D-6651CC36E5AA}
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:265]: SOURCEMGMT: Media is enabled for product.
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:265]: SOURCEMGMT: Attempting to use LastUsedSource from source list.
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:265]: SOURCEMGMT: Trying source d:\2a2ac35788eea9066bae01\.
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:265]: Note: 1: 2203 2: d:\2a2ac35788eea9066bae01\msxml6.msi 3: -2147287037 
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:265]: SOURCEMGMT: Source is invalid due to missing/inaccessible package.
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:265]: Note: 1: 1706 2: -2147483647 3: msxml6.msi 
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:265]: SOURCEMGMT: Processing net source list.
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:265]: Note: 1: 1706 2: -2147483647 3: msxml6.msi 
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:265]: SOURCEMGMT: Processing media source list.
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:296]: SOURCEMGMT: Trying media source F:\.
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:296]: Note: 1: 2203 2: F:\msxml6.msi 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:296]: SOURCEMGMT: Source is invalid due to missing/inaccessible package.
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:296]: Note: 1: 1706 2: -2147483647 3: msxml6.msi 
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:296]: SOURCEMGMT: Processing URL source list.
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:296]: Note: 1: 1402 2: UNKNOWN\URL 3: 2 
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:296]: Note: 1: 1706 2: -2147483647 3: msxml6.msi 
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:296]: Note: 1: 1706 2:  3: msxml6.msi 
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:296]: SOURCEMGMT: Failed to resolve source
MSI (s) (90:DC) [16:38:12:296]: MainEngineThread is returning 1612
MSI (c) (DC:58) [16:38:12:296]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (DC:58) [16:38:12:296]: MainEngineThread is returning 1612
=== Verbose logging stopped: 3/28/2012  16:38:12 ===
```

When I click on the failed status for SSIS, no log file appears at all.  To be honest, I'm not even sure where to start on this one - never guessed it would be so much trouble to add a component right from the disk.  Any help or pointers whatsoever would be greatly appreciated.  If any more details are needed, please ask - I'd be glad to add them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part of those log files that stood out for me was this:

```
Source is invalid due to invalid package code (product code doesn't
match)
```

Google turned this up which looks relevant to me:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2009/07/23/sql-server-setup-prompts-with-the-installed-product-does-not-match-the-installation-source-s-part-i.aspx

Comment: This helped loads actually, now the only component failing is MSXML6, but this could be because we never implemented SP3 (I know I know).  Regardless, with enough work, I believe I can get this to work.  Took 3+ hrs of work using above link to get to this point.

Answer (score 0):

Your errors seem to indicate that the Windows Installer cache files are missing.

Check out this link: [How to restore the missing Windows Installer cache files and resolve problems that occur during a SQL Server update](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/969052)